# Running system command fails but the same command works executed directly in bash

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I am running the following code in perl

```
my $exp_date = `date --date="$(openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in certificate.pem | cut -d= -f 2)"  --iso-8601`;
```

and I get:

> date: invalid date ‘100 100 537 539 847 6210 70720 7....

The exact command run in the command line

```
date --date="$(openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in certificate.pem | cut -d= -f 2)"  --iso-8601
```

prints the actual date in iso8601.

What am I doing wrong when running it in Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Perl special variable `$(` [(see the documentation)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$REAL_GROUP_ID) contains the real group id of the process. Backticks interpolate variables. To prevent interpolation, escape the dollar sign by a backslash:

```perl
my $exp_date = `date --date="\$(openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in certificate.pem | cut -d= -f 2)"  --iso-8601`;
#                            ~
```

Comment: That worked! So if I understand correctly the problem was that `$(` captures the group id of the current process and it was added before the `openssl` part of the command?

Comment: Also is there an issue if I do `return \`date --date=\$.....` instead of using the `$exp_date` as intermediate variable and return that from the `sub` this code is executed?

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue. And yes, all variables are interpolated in backticks.